VBA Excel - identify duplicates and rearrange them
I created the following macro and got stucked. So, I need to identify duplicates in column A and rearrange them in separate columns starting from the column left to column B according to a defined layout. If I find a new unique duplicate, macro should go back to the first column left to the column B und this column should be used as an insertion point.
That means all duplicates of the same occurrences should be placed in one column (2nd together, 3rd together and so on). However, I get a new column every time it finds a duplicate (even if it has a new value) and this column shifts to the left.
I used loop because the dataset is not constant, and the number of duplicates may vary.
I appreciate any help :)

Here is my VBA I created.
Sub testworking()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim colIndex As Long

    Dim colDict As Object
    Set colDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        value = ws.Cells(i, 1).value
        If dict.Exists(value) Then
            colIndex = colDict(value) - 1 ' Adjust to insert left to B
            If colIndex < 2 Then ' Ensure we do not go beyond column A
                colIndex = 2
            End If
            ws.Columns(colIndex).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            ws.Cells(i, colIndex).value = value
        Else
            dict.Add value, 1
            colDict.Add value, ws.Cells(i, 1).Column ' Store the initial column index
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Here is a dataset I got after macro has been performed. It is shifting every time it has found a duplicate (even if it is a new unique value).


Will duplicate values always be together in sequential rows? Must you do this with VBA? It's probably possible with formulas though you will need to add the columns manually

In your sample the values in the Subclass column (A, B, C...) always seem to reset when a new complaint starts. Is this actually the case? If yes, you should be able to use this to determine if a new column needs to be added or not.

It would be so much easier to just create a pivot table, as your original source data is already perfect for that.

Duplicates values are always together in sequential rows and are unique. I need to use VBA because the dataset may contain around 1000 values. I simplified the Subclass column to provide the better understanding. It is not always A,B,C and not in this order.

Yes, a pivot table would be much easier. But I need to use this layout for furtgher evaluation. The point is I don't understand how I can write "go back to the column left to B, if there is a new duplicate value". All duplicates in A are grouped together and are nor repeating

Try this out:
Sub testworking()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, r As Long, v
    Dim maxCols As Long, dict As Object, col As Range, insCols As Long
    Dim c As Range, n As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2")
    Set col = ws.Columns(2)
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'find the number of columns needed for insertion
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
        v = c.value
        dict(v) = dict(v) + 1
        If insCols < dict(v) Then insCols = dict(v)
    Next c
    If insCols = 1 Then Exit Sub 'no duplicates
    
    ws.Columns(2).Resize(, insCols - 1).Insert 'insert extra columns
    
    'distribute replicates
    For Each c In ws.Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Cells
        v = c.value
        If v = c.Offset(-1).value Then
            n = n + 1 'increment count
            c.Offset(0, insCols - n) = v
        Else
            n = 0     'reset count
        End If
    Next c
End Sub


I tried out your code with different sets of values and that works almost perfect! The only problem is if the arranging is adjusted to the highest number of duplicates. Take the example from the thread and let's assume "123" occurs only twice and "256" four times. In this case "123" will be inserted not immediately right to the column B. What should I change in your code?

I think the code I posted matches your intended output, with the exception of that "123" in colB, which look out of place compared to the other numbers in your screenshot?  Maybe you can explain the exact rules?  How do you avoid inserting enough columns to handle the number with the highest count of replicates?

Yes, it does, but "123" in column B is the point. The first insertion of every duplicate should be always left to the column B. Duplicates of the same order should be placed in one column together. The count of duplicates is limited by 10. Let's say the value "A" occurs twice and the value "B" ten times. The "A" duplicate will be placed together with the ninth "B" duplicate in one column what is a mistake. I hope It is clear enough

See updated code - I understand (I think) how it should work.

Nice, now the code is working the way I need it. Thanks a lot!
